# Mongoose & MongoDB, find() except one that contains one property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im looking for a condition in `Mongoose` that allows me to find all the users except the ones that haves the role `'Admin':2000`. Mind that the admin users also has anothers roles, like "User" and "Editor", like this:

```
{
   "name": "John Doe Admin",
   "roles": {
           "Admin": 555,
           "Editor": 556,
           "User": 557
          }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `$ne` operator? `.find({ 'roles.Admin': { $ne: 2000 } })`

Comment: YEEEAASSS, that does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the comments is the answer:

```
.find({ 'roles.Admin': { $ne: 2000 } })
```